# How to output a string, the result is (null)?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

How to output a pointer string, the print result is "**(null)**" just like outputting a char?

Comment: No idea what you are asking. `char *str = "(null)";`???

Comment: `char str` is not a pointer, yet `NULL` is the null pointer macro. You have undefined behavior when you try to print the contents of `str` with `%s`, which expects a _string_ (i.e., a null-terminated character array). And for `char *str = "\0"`, first there is no need for the `\0`-- just use `char *str = ""` for an empty string; second, this does not print a space; it prints nothing (before the `\n` in your format string.)

Comment: "I cannot see the output, it's a space I think." No, it's no output at all since you gave it a 0-length string.

Comment: Thank you guys! I just want to write a function likes strstr(), but I have no idea to return a string pointer to main, and the return value print as "(null)".

Comment: Start from the C beginners book.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I just want to write a function which likes strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle). This function returns a pointer to the first occurrence in haystack of any of the entire sequence of characters specified in needle, or a null pointer if the sequence is not present in haystack. Then how to properly return a null pointer to main()? @Bo Persson

Comment: Yes. I will. thanks for your response. @PeterJ

Comment: @W.S - I might not fully understand what you are doing, but returning a null pointer would just be `return NULL;`.

Comment: THANK YOU! This is exactly what I want! @luk2302

Comment: If I return a null pointer, and there is a "Segmentation fault" when I printf the string. @Bo Persson

Answer (score -3):

```
printf("%s\n", *str ? str : "(null)");
```

If the first character pointed to by str is '\0', the above will print (null).  Otherwise, it will print the string pointed to by str.

To also handle the case:

```
char *str = NULL;
```

...use:

```
printf("%s\n", (str && *str)?str:"(null)");
```